# How to get curl verbose output without the TLS negotiation?

Tags: curl

Is there a curl option producing everything like `-v` except for the TLS negotiation? I need both the input and output headers, but don't care about TLS as I know it works.

Answer (score 5):

Not as of `curl` 7.70.0 (released April 2020) [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

The best you can do is to filter the `-v` output, e.g.

```
$ curl -sv -I https://google.com 2>&1 | grep '^[<>]'  
> HEAD / HTTP/2
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/2 301 
< location: https://www.google.com/
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< date: Wed, 06 May 2020 01:05:57 GMT
...
```